# Как перевернуть Map, чтобы ключ стал значением, а значение ключом?

Tags: java, map

```java
Student student1 = new Student("Ivan", "Ivanov");
Student student2 = new Student("Nikolay", "Petrov");
Student student3 = new Student("Kirill", "Antipov");
Course matematic = new Course("Matematic");
Course philosophy = new Course("Philosophy");
Course english = new Course("English");
Course physics = new Course("Physics");
Course franch = new Course("Franch");

Map<Student, List<Course>> education = new HashMap<Student, List<Course>>();

education.put(student1, Arrays.asList(matematic, english, philosophy));
education.put(student2, Arrays.asList(matematic, english, physics));
education.put(student3, Arrays.asList());
```

Совсем не понимаю, как это возможно осуществить, не создавая новую карту.

Comment: Вижу некоторое противоречие между задачей перевернуть `Map` и требованием не создавать новый объект...Как вы перевернутую мэпу сохраните в объект типа `Map<Student, List<Course>>`?

Comment: Пожалуй не правильно изьяснился.  Не создавать новую Map, тем же путем что и сущетвующую . Ведь если элемнтов  будет 100+ это совсем не удобно.

Comment: А какой смысл иметь карту с ключом - списком предметов?  К тому же, при "переворачивании" у вас скорее всего возникнет ситуация, когда одному ключу - списку будет отвечать несколько разных студентов, и при простом переприсваивании может быть частично потеряна информация.  Как вы планируете разрешать такой конфликт?

Comment: Разве HashMap не хранит хеши ключей вместо них самих?

Comment: @MyCatBulka, можете посмотреть [исходный код реализации `HashMap`](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java) Там создаётся массив узлов `Node<K,V>`, и _обработанный_ хеш-код ключа записывается как поле узла: `Node(int hash, K key, V value, Node<K,V> next)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как по мне, то это изобретение велосипеда. Эту проблему давно решили. Например, таким решением есть bimap от guava. Метод, который перевернет Map, называется inverse.

Подробный гид можете найти здесь:

https://www.baeldung.com/guava-bimap

Comment: Ну и попробуй написать с ней пример со списками - как в вопросе...

Comment: `BiMap` вряд ли подойдёт для данной задачи, она предназначена для двунаправленных карт, где уникальны как ключи, так и значения: [_A `BiMap<K, V>` is a `Map<K, V>` that ... ensures that values are unique, making `values()` a `Set`_](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#bimap)

Comment: Спасибо!! Ранее не встречал этот метод.

Answer (score 4):

Если нужно построить "обратную" мапу вида `Map<Course, List<Student>>`, можно использовать метод `Map::computeIfAbsent`, чтобы создать список значений для "нового" ключа, и добавить в него "старый" ключ.

Обобщённое решение для любых пар типов `K, V` (для итерации используются методы `Map::forEach`, `List::forEach`)

```java
public static<K, V> Map<V, List<K>> convert(Map<K, List<V>> map) {
    Map<V, List<K>> result = new HashMap<>(); // new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.forEach((key, vals) -> vals.forEach(
        v -> result.computeIfAbsent(v, kk -> new ArrayList<>()).add(key)
    ));
    return result;
}
```

---

Возможно решение при помощи Stream API, но оно будет более громоздкое

```java
public static<K, V> Map<V, List<K>> convert(Map<K, List<V>> map) {
    return map.entrySet()
        .stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<K, List<V>>>
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream() // Stream<V>
            .map(v -> Map.entry(v, e.getKey())) 
        )         // Stream<Map.Entry<V, K>>
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())
        ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так (писал тут, так что могут быть ошибки):

```
var res = new HashMap<Course, List<Student>>();

for (var entry : education.entrySet()) {
  var student = entry.getKey();

  for (var course : entry.getValue()) {
    var list = res.get(course);
    if (list == null) res.put(course, list = new ArrayList());
    list.add(student);
  }
}
```

Comment: @NowhereMan, предположительно исправил.